# MATLAB: Issues getting 'UserData' from an axes

Tags: image, matlab, user-data

My aim is to create a toggle button out of images, and to be able to retrieve the state of the toggle button by other functions. I have done this by storing information in userdata and acting upon that information accordingly. However, I have encountered a problem when retrieving the userdata in some functions. The code I am having issues with is like this one below:

```
    % --- Executes on mouse press over axes background.
    function image1_Select(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    data = get(handles.axes1, 'UserData');

    if data == '1'  % was enabled
      data = '0';
      set(handles.button, 'enable', 'off') %controls a different button
      image = imread('im1.jpg');
      set(handles.axes1, 'CData', image) %when pressed, the image displayed toggles
    elseif data == '0' % was disabled
      data = '1';
      set(handles.button, 'enable', 'on')
      image = imread('im2.jpg');
      set(handles.axes1, 'CData', image)
    else
      errordlg('There has been an error, try again', 'Error')
      data = '0';
      set(handles.button, 'enable', 'off')
      image = imread('im1.jpg');
      set(handles.axes1, 'CData', image)
    end

    set(handles.axes1, 'UserData', data)

    % --- Executes on mouse press over axes background.
    function image2_Select(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    data = get(handles.axes2, 'UserData');

    if data == '1'  % was enabled
      data = '0';
      set(handles.button2, 'enable', 'off')
      image = imread('otherim1.jpg');
      set(handles.axes2, 'CData', image)
    elseif data == '0' % was disabled
      data = '1';
      set(handles.button2, 'enable', 'on')
      image = imread('otherim2.jpg');
      set(handles.axes2, 'CData', image)
    else
      errordlg('There has been an error, try again', 'Error')
      data = '0';
      set(handles.button2, 'enable', 'off')
      image = imread('otherim1.jpg');
      set(handles.axes2, 'CData', image)
    end

    set(handles.axes2, 'UserData', data)
    testdata = get(handles.axes1, 'UserData')

    function load(hObject, eventdata, handles)
      data1 = get(handles.axes1, 'UserData')
      data2 = get(handles.axes2, 'UserData')
      %other code, the above are the first lines in the function
```

`testdata` returns '1' (if `set1` was called before it) but both `data1` and `data2` return `[ ]` when they should return '1' since both `set1` and `set2` are called before `load`.
What is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that they're called the way you think (i.e. `set1()` and `set2()` before `retrieve()`)? Just add to each function a specific `display` call, e.g. `display('In set1');` at the end of the function `set1`, to make sure which function is called when.

Comment: We need more information on how your GUI functions. I am unable to replicate the issue with a simple GUI.

Comment: @CST-Link, I know they are called before because they are called when I click on images, which is what I do before clicking the load button.

Comment: @excaza I have put more detail into my code so hopefully my issue is clearer now.

Comment: @HRoot I am still unable to replicate this issue with the given code. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As an aside, you are overloading the built in [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) and [`image`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) functions. I would highly recommend not doing this.

Comment: @HRoot I am testing using [this code](https://github.com/sco1/testcode/blob/master/testcode.m)

Comment: @excaza I'll try create the better code, thanks for the link. Meanwhile, I don't know whether this will be the reason why you aren't getting the problem but I'm not using buttons to change the axes images, I am clicking on the axes figure itself. Also, the names I provided above aren't the ones I'm using in the code, I just thought it would be easier to read that way, but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @HRoot Both codes are referencing the `handles` structure so the behavior should be the same. It's just a different method of invoking the callback because I didn't feel like coding the other.

Comment: @excaza oh ok. After working on the code yesterday I got it working thanks to your direction and an answer from another question I forgot I had asked previously. Thanks for all your help!